# "trespass" in fewer than nine words or 17 syllables

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, legal-terminology

In Chapter 3 of Robert Heinlein's *Starman Jones*, we find this:

> Vagrancy in the eyes of the law had not worried him, nor trespass, nor impersonating a licensed teamster—but filching a book was a sin.

The translation into German by Kurt Seibt and Rainer Schumacher, bearing the title *Gestrandet im Sternenreich*, is as follows:

> Eine mögliche Angklage wegen Landstreicherei hatte Max nicht beunruhigt; ebensowenig die Tatsache, daß er auf verbotenen Wegen gegangen war, oder daß er vertäuschte, ein qualifiziertes Mitglied der Fuhrmannsgilde zu sein, aber ein Buch zu unterschlagen . . . das war eine Sünde.

I was surprised to see the single two-syllable word *trespass [on land]* rendered as *die Tatsache, daß er auf verbotenen Wegen gegangen war,* so that one word became nine and two syllables became 17. Is there no terse German locution for *trespass?*

Comment: "Trespass" literally translated is "unbefugt betreten" oder "widerrechtlich betreten". This is a little bit shorter, but in deed there is no single word in german for this expression.

Comment: At Spanish Beta, we have a new game called Translation Golf, where we compete in a friendly way to make as concise a translation as possible, with a different paragraph per week.  This text seems like a good candidate for such a game.  See https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/9385

Comment: Apparent follow-up question on [law.se]: [Entering private property that is not enclosed](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/18379/906)

Comment: Is it only me, or does "auf verbotenen Wegen gegangen" sound quite a bit more figurative than the literal legal meaning of "tresspass" that is assumed here? In German, I'd find it really weird if someone told me I must not enter a certain place or path by saying "Dieser Weg ist verboten." That is really unidiomatic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : But what happened in the story is that the protagonist went through a tunnel through which trains pass and otherwise walked through forbidden grounds.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: In German, I would never express that as a "verbotener Tunnel" or a "verbotenes Grundstück". That just sounds wrong and, if anything, makes me assume the *existence* of the tunnel/ground themselves was forbidden (like e.g. if they were built without authorization). At best, it's "ein für Fußgänger verbotener Tunnel", but even that sounds rather literary (and, despite that text being a work of literature, somewhat unfitting in the concrete context of legal offenses).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : My comment was not intended to suggest any particular way of expressing anything in German.

Answer (score 2):

**Legally**, the English *[trespass to land](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_land)* and the [German *Hausfriedensbruch*](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausfriedensbruch_(Deutschland)) are mostly analogous: You unlawfully and intentionally enter another’s land. So, technically *Hausfriedensbruch* would be an acceptable translation, if you do not care about legal detail. However, the [Austrian *Hausfriedensbruch*](//www.jusline.at/109_Hausfriedensbruch_StGB.html) is different as it requires the use or threat of violence, and [in Switzerland the land in question must belong to a house](//www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/19370083/index.html#a186).

In **everyday use**, there is a considerable difference though beginning with the words themselves:

- *Trespass* is usually used for entering land excluding buildings. If buildings are entered, there are stronger terms like *unlawful entry.*
- *Hausfriedensbruch* is usually used for entering buildings. While it does apply to land, most people aren’t even aware of this due to its name (I had to look it up myself).

I hypothesise that this difference also reflects a cultural difference: In the Anglosphere, trespassing land is considered a stronger invasion than in Germany. This is reflected by fenced or otherwise delineated large areas of land being more common.

Hence, in **the context in question** where the focus is most likely on land and not buildings, *Hausfriedensbruch* does not really work. Also, due to the aforementioned cultural differences it is not surprising that there is no short word for this in German.

However, *Hausfriedensbruch* can be used as a basis for creating a new word for this purpose. The naïve solution, *[Landfriedensbruch](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landfriedensbruch),* is already reserved for endangering public order, but *Grundstücksfriedensbruch* is still free, has the same emphasis as *trespass to land,* and should be immediately understandable.

Comment: The "trespass" offense simply doesn't exist in German law. Things you can do wrong by trespassing are covered by a myriad of other offenses in German law.

Comment: It's important to understand the concept behind it. Especially legal terminology can seldom be translated one by one. "Unbefugtes Betreten" is about as close as we can get. _Hausfriedensbruch_ conveys an element of violence (which is explicitly the case in Austrian penal law, e.g.) that simple _trespassing_ does not. In Germany, too, there must be either walls or fences, which is not the case for the common law _trespass to land_.

Comment: _Grundstücksfriedensbruch_? Certainly not. Unless you write a future novel where you get to make up your own society and crimes, this is a no-starter if you want a serious translation.

Comment: @Ingmar: "In Germany, too, there must be either walls or fences, which is not the case for the common law *trespass to land*." - now, it would be interesting to resolve the apparent contradiction with this answer, which assumes fences as the usual thing "in England and America", as opposed to Germany. In other words, the answer implies that in the Anglosphere, trespassing to land is a severe matter *precisely because* land over there is typically fenced, whereas you imply that *tresspass to land* in the Anglosphere is different from the German counterpart because it does *not* assume fences.

Comment: @Ingmar: Hausfriedensbruch *conveys an element of violence (which is explicitly the case in Austrian penal law, e.g.) that simple* trespassing *does not. – Apparently, this legal term is used differently in Austria. In Germany and Switzerland, there clearly is no element of violence required for *Hausfriedensbruch.* (See my edit.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I neither said that fences are the usual thing in the Anglosphere nor that the existence of fences makes trespassing different. The different use of fences and similar merely reflects the different attitude to trespassing (which I made clearer in my answer now). For example [this](//2ff8n03drmib1b12373aauek-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/assets/images/Blog-Building/Hedge%20Laying/52.jpg) would be an unusual sight in Germany.

Comment: I know that _Hausfriedensbruch_ does not require violence under the German legal system (unless the Austrian one, which does), but the term itself (Friedensbruch, i.e. lit. _breaking of the peace_) certainly has similar roots. To repeat, in my opinion "Unbefugtes Betreten" would be the most general translation.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the above - widerrechtlich betreten. One has to understand that Heinlein had a strong sense of ironic humor. The very legal "sins" he mentions here are the parodies of a "righteous" man. A serious legal translation would do the original intent (meiner Meingung nach) harm.

Answer (score -1):

**wiederrechtliches Betreten**

Betreten however is a Nound and not a verb.

**wiederrechtliches durchqueren** could work though